# How to append aggregated vectors for keyed data as a new column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

My R problem is the following: I have a data.frame from an SQL database (let's say security cash flows: 'cf_table'). The primary key is of 3 columns:

```
security_id, quote_date, future_cf_date, (and 'x')
```

On the 4th column (e.g. 'x') I shall make some computations what returns a vector (instead of single value), in my example `rev(cumsum(rev(x)))` -- backward cumulated sums, **grouped by the first two cols**. In other words: "What is the backward cumulated sums of future cashflows of a security by quote day?" 'x' is sparse, it has mainly NAs.  How can I accomplish this task? I tried `dplyr`, `data.table` etc. without success. My goal is to append this new column to my original table.

For reproducibility please see the end of my post.

Any idea? (By the way, is `rev(cumsum(rev(x)))` efficient or elegant?)

Sample data:

```
cf_table <- structure(list(security_id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), quote_date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2014.05.13", 
"2015.04.13", "2015.04.14", "2015.04.15"), class = "factor"), 
    CF.Dátum = structure(c(3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("2014.12.22", 
    "2015.06.22", "2015.06.24", "2015.12.22", "2016.06.24", "2017.06.26", 
    "2018.06.25", "2019.06.24", "2020.06.24", "2021.06.24", "2022.06.24"
    ), class = "factor"), future_cf_date = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2000L, NA, 10000L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2000L, NA, 10000L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10000L, NA, 500L, 10000L, NA, 
    NA, 10000L, NA, NA, 10000L), My.desired.output = c(12000L, 
    12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 10000L, 10000L, 12000L, 
    12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 12000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 
    10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10500L, 
    10500L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L
    )), .Names = c("security_id", "quote_date", "future_cf_date", "x", 
"My.desired.output"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `ave` from `base R` without using any packages.

```
with(cf_table, ave(replace(x, is.na(x), 0), security_id, quote_date, 
           FUN = function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x)))))
#[1] 12000 12000 12000 12000 12000 12000 10000 10000 12000 12000 12000 12000 12000 12000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
#[25] 10500 10500 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000 10000
```

#### Benchmarks

```
cf_ave <- function() with(cf_table, ave(replace(x, is.na(x), 0), 
    security_id, quote_date, 
        FUN = function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x)))))
system.time(cf_ave())
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0 

system.time(cf_table_reduce())
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.00    0.05    0.06 

system.time(cf_table_rev())
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.01    0.00    0.02 

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(cf_ave(), cf_table_reduce(), cf_table_rev(),
                      unit = "relative", times = 20L)
#Unit: relative
#            expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#         cf_ave()  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.00000    20
#cf_table_reduce() 11.098189 9.945726 9.339097 8.648005 8.489285 10.58431    20
#   cf_table_rev()  7.825883 7.090710 6.659378 6.031240 6.075992  8.93274    20
```

On a bigger dataset

```
cf_table1 <- copy(cf_table)
set.seed(24)
cf_table <- data.frame(security_id = sample(letters, 1e7, replace = TRUE), 
     quote_date = sample(unique(cf_table$quote_date), 1e7, replace = TRUE), 
    x= sample(10000:20000, 1e7, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
cf_table$x[sample(1e7, 1e6, replace=FALSE)] <- NA
microbenchmark(cf_ave(), cf_table_reduce(), cf_table_rev(),
                  unit = "relative", times = 20L)
#Unit: relative
#             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#         cf_ave()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    20
#cf_table_reduce() 13.909809 13.898210 13.913709 13.778034 13.411617 16.466479    20
#   cf_table_rev()  1.077809  1.091534  1.086552  1.099303  1.074822  1.111652    20
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Reduce` function and accumulate from the right hand side of the vector `x`, which will act just like `cumsum` backward:

```
library(dplyr)
cf_table_reduce = function() cf_table %>% group_by(security_id, quote_date) %>% 
  mutate(back_sum = Reduce(function(i,j) sum(i,j,na.rm = T), x, right = T, accumulate = T))
```

Another option with `rev(cumsum(rev))` is to replace `NA` values in x with zero, since `cumsum` function cannot handle `NA` values:

```
cf_table_rev = function() cf_table %>% group_by(security_id, quote_date) %>% 
  mutate(x = replace(x, is.na(x), 0), back_sum = rev(cumsum(rev(x))))
```

*Results*:

```
identical(cf_table_rev(), cf_table_reduce())
# [1] TRUE

sum(cf_table_rev()$back_sum == cf_table$My.desired.output) == nrow(cf_table)
# [1] TRUE
```

As for the speed, these two methods seem to be close:

```
microbenchmark(cf_table_rev(), cf_table_reduce())
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#     cf_table_rev() 212.2586 225.9167 332.3184 410.3508 431.9465 452.0192   100
#  cf_table_reduce() 211.2370 225.0572 331.7268 412.5145 432.1195 453.0889   100
```

The dimension of the data I use for comparison is:

```
dim(cf_table)
# [1] 2162688       5
```

Comment: In data.table, the second approach can be done without `rev`s. Dunno if it's fast or not: `library(data.table); setDT(cf_table)[.N:1, v := cumsum(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)), by=.(security_id, quote_date)]`